# How can I see which native dll's are loaded by the JVM?

Tags: java, dll, jvm, libpng

I am debugging an application in IntelliJ, and the JVM complains about the version of libpng:

```
QSystemTrayIcon::setVisible: No Icon set
libpng warning: Application was compiled with png.h from libpng-1.4.0
libpng warning: Application  is  running with png.c from libpng-1.2.46
libpng error: Incompatible libpng version in application and library
```

I would like to check which libpng file (i.e. the full path to the file) is being loaded during the execution of my java program. How can I do that?

The next question would be: how can I ensure that it loads libpng version 1.4.0 (it is on my system, but apparently it finds libpng  1.2.46 first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Unix, you can look at all the mappings.  If a shared library is loaded you can see it under `/proc/{pid}/maps` e.g.

```
address           perms offset  dev   inode   pathname
08048000-08056000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
08056000-08058000 rw-p 0000d000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
08058000-0805b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
40000000-40013000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
40013000-40015000 rw-p 00012000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
4001f000-40135000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
40135000-4013e000 rw-p 00115000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
4013e000-40142000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
bffff000-c0000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
```

http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc